# How to change windows style with MaterialDesign in wpf

Tags: wpf, material-design

I use MaterialDesign  for style controls in wpf add.
I change all controls use MaterialDesign  theme. I want to change windows style(WindowTitle, close,min,max button).
How to change this?

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you need to set Window Style (Border settings) = None and need to set user controls manually and apply code as per your requirement.

Or you can built your own custom control for this.